# should I allow "." in URL?

Tags: php, codeigniter, url, web, url-masking

I am doing URL masking by using codeigniter routing. Here I allow user to enter a text which will be URL of his offer details on under a specific URL.

ie,if user entered "offer1" then his offer details will be available on

> [offers.com/offer/offer1](http://offers.com/offer/offer1)

Here I accept only alphabets and numbers as URL text.Should I allow "." in URL text? What is the standard method should I follow here?

Comment: when he enters the offer name encode it using base64_encode() and send to url and if you want to use it later decode it using base64_decode() .....let me know if you face any problems

Comment: `.` should be fine, check this: http://www.blooberry.com/indexdot/html/topics/urlencoding.htm#whatwhy (although not related to codeigniter, which might have it's own rules, depending on how it works, which I'm not sure about)

Comment: urlencoding gives soem disallowed characters when you encode text....

Comment: Why not? `urlencode` works well.

Comment: urlencode gives disallowed characters in some cases............

Comment: after trying base64 also if you face let me know whats the error........

Comment: A `.` is a valid character allowed and should not cause any problems, just make sure your CI routing config will allow its use.

Comment: @Venkat Are you sure? What character do you mean?

Comment: I am damn sure because i faced same problems i rectified it using base64_encode().......

Comment: I have used `urldecode` and its works well.

Comment: what about urlencode........is it working perfectly

Comment: If urlencode doesn't work for you it's possible [rawurlencode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rawurlencode.php) could do the trick.

Comment: I think `urlencode` automatically happening and only `urldecode` is needed.In my program I have used only `urldecode` and find it as working well.

Comment: k no problem your problem solved right ........all is well

Comment: Regarding to the point that . is valid character, its confusing because such url like (.com/url.php) its like a file with php extension, another (.com/url.jpeg) it appear as an image! its a kind of URL cloaking attack :)

Comment: @Akam thank you for noticing about the security. Actually I had doubt about the security.My client given choice for allowing "." character as well as dis-allowing "." character.Then better method is dis-allowing "." character?

Comment: I suggest using [a-zA-Z0-9-] as white list, then you can use $url = preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9]+/', '', $url);

Answer (score 0):

When user enters the offer name take that as `$offer_name` and encode it using `base64_encode($offer_name);`

```
$encoded_name = base64_encode($offer_name);
```

Send this `$encoded_name` to url...........and if you want to use offer name further decode it using `base64_decode($encoded_name);`

Comment: i don't know the difference dude i faced problem like this i tried urlencode it gave disallowed characters so i tried base64_encode()

Comment: urlencode is supposed to take strings and make them URL safe, base64_encode encodes things in [base64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64).

Answer (score 0):

if you need the "." you can leave that in urls, if you then use url params to run queries just escape params before to run the query.

Usually i make a `301 redirect` to the `base_url();` if somenthing wrong with url params.

just my 2 cents

Answer (score 0):

You can allow `"."` in URL by adding `"."` in `$config['permitted_uri_chars']` config variable in `config.php`.